# toggle display only working on second click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` that is `display:none` which should appear when an icon is clicked. My function works but always on the ***second*** click. Any ideas what's wrong with the function?

```
document.getElementById('icon').onclick = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('div');
    if ( el.style.display != 'none' ){
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    };
};
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your problem?

Comment: What browsers have you tested with?

Comment: are you trying to select a div, or an html element with an id of "div"?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2hobbk7u/1/

Comment: i've tested in both chrome and IE, i'm selecting a div to display:block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your test to the "positive"

```
if ( el.style.display == 'block' ){
```

And it will work.

The default is probably not exactly 'none'.

Using jQuery would make that a lot easier, see http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Using jQuery would make that a lot heavier as well :)

Comment: hey Alexis, this worked! Is there an explanation as to why? my default css is display:none for the div.

Comment: As I was saying in my answer, the 'none' is not always viewed as 'none' (it will also depend on the browser.) I do not know exactly why. Something I bumped into, just like you... 8-)

Answer (score 2):

`el.style` would refer to `inline` style , not `global` style.

so change your code to

```
<div id="nav_form_container" style="display:none">
```

and the code will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/2hobbk7u/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I believe what you may have been doing was using the div as a selector instead of an ID on your variable.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ocvLq8bn/)

**HTML:**

```
<button id="icon">Test Button</button>
<div id="test" style="display: none;">I am hidden</div>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('icon').onclick = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    if ( el.style.display != 'none' ){
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    };
};
```