# Why is my hide/unhide button only working on the second click?

Tags: javascript

I just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255486/toggle-display-only-working-on-second-click), but the answers don't seem to help me. Also, I would think that this code would initially have the tables hidden but that's also not working. This is for a chrome extension so cross browser functionality is unnecessary. Pure javascript answers only, please.

```
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {  

        tables = main_pm_node.getElementsByClassName('featureOptions');
        //alert("outside - number of tables found: " + tables.length);

        if(tables.length > 0){
            observer.disconnect();
            console.log("number of tables found: " + tables.length);
            for(i=0; i<tables.length; i++){
                (function(i) {
                    var sp = document.createElement('span');
                    var act_table = document.createElement('table');
                    act_table.id = 'act-tests-' + i;
                    act_table.style = 'display:none';//'visibility: visible';
                    act_table.innerHTML ='<tbody>blah blah html html</tbody>';
                    sp.appendChild(act_table);

                    tables[i].parentElement.appendChild(sp);
                    var row   = tables[i].insertRow(-1);
                    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
                    cell1.className = "optionLabel pull-left";

                    var button = document.createElement('button');
                    button.innerHTML = 'Show ACT tests';
                    button.className = 'btn pull-left';
                    button.type = 'button';
                    button.onclick = function(){
                        var lTable = document.getElementById(act_table.id);
                        console.log(act_table.id + ' ' + lTable);
                        lTable.style.display = (lTable.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
                    };

                    cell1.appendChild(button); //.innerHTML = '<input class="btn pull-left" type="button" onclick="toggleTable();" value="Show ACT tests"/>' ;
                })(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. `act_table.style = 'display:none'` will not hide the element, you shall use `act_table.style.display = "none"` instead
2. Now that act_table is not hidden, the `lTable.style.display` will be empty string, not block, so the table will only be hidden after second click(first click will set `lTable.style.display = "block"`, and when clicked again,  `(lTable.style.display == 'block')` will be fulfilled)

Comment: yes. I just found this and came back to answer but you beat me to it! Thanks